# How can I join the Google accounts for two email addresses?

Tags: google-account

I've heard that Google has supported, for a while now, multiple email addresses linked to a single account. Now, I've had, for many years already, accounts for two addresses of mine - with different group memberships etc. Can I merge these two accounts somehow? And if so, how?

Comment: There is no way to "merge" two Google accounts.

Comment: Are you certain? And no workaround?

Comment: I am a certain the Google offers no method to merge two entirely separate Google accounts I am `00% positive of that fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't currently possible to merge separate Google Accounts.

Source: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/63304?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

While you may not be able to merge Google accounts into one, you certainly can manage your e-mail using one Google account.

The preferred way to manage multiple accounts is to simply log into multiple accounts at once.

Steps:

- Click your user icon in the top right corner
- Click Add Account
- Log into your other account
- Use this method to switch between accounts

To address your one account question, take these steps:

1. Open Settings on your primary account (click the top right gear icon then Settings)
2. Open the Accounts tab
3. Click 'Add another email address you own' link in the 'Send mail as' section
4. Enter your other email address. (Choose the options that best fit your preferences)
5. Look for the verification email in your Other account and follow the steps found there.
6. Use the one e-mail account to send / receive email

Pay careful attention to the 'When replying to a message:' setting

Good Luck and let us know how it works out for you.

Comment: The next step would be to either set the "Add a POP3.." account setting to your primary email account    OR  Set forwarding in your secondary account to send to your primary account.

Comment: Umm, thanks, but I don't actually need to merge the accounts for managing email: user1@not-google.com and user2@someplace-else-but-not-google.net